# python 2.7 SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, for-loop, eof

For some reason I am getting **SyntaxError: EOF** while scanning triple-quoted string literals.

It needs to check the number if user enters 8, it prints a **B**

```
a >= 0.9 
b >= 0.8
c >= 0.7 
d >= 0.6 
f <= 0.5 

number = float(raw_input('enter 0.8: '))

if number != 0.8:
   raise ValueError("didn't enter 0.8")

i = 0
for i in (a, b ,c ,d, f): 
       if number == i:
          print i
```

Here is a the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/home/dux/untitled0.py", line 39 """0.9, 0.8, 0.7,0.6, 0.5):""
^ SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal –
```

Comment: It would helpful to include the triple quoted string literal and the error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/dux/untitled0.py", line 39
    """0.9, 0.8, 0.7,0.6, 0.5):""
                                ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Comment: line 39 """0.9, 0.8, 0.7,0.6, 0.5):"" - is missing a " at the end

Comment: fixed one error, but it is printing a number instead of a letter